# ExpressJS app server returns 502 after several of requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm a fresh graduate developer and a new learner to ExpressJS.
I have an application server which is written in ExpressJS framework. After the website send a couple of xhr to it, the server starts returning 502 status.

[image: This is the server response]

Here's my code to start the application server:

```
let app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let id = guid();
    req['id'] = id;
    next();
})

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    for (let i in req.body) {
        if (typeof req.body[i] === 'string')
            req.body[i] = decodeURIComponent(req.body[i]);
    }
    next();
})

// Establish database object
app.use('/', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        req.db = new TDBHelper(pool);
        next();
    }
    catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
})

app.use('/file', express.static(__dirname + '/../bin/file'));

app.use('/api/v1', router);

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    await req.db.end();
    // Route not found.
    const error = new Error();
    error.message = 'API not found.';
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
})

// On Error Handling
app.use(async (err, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    await req.db.rollback();
    console.log(err);
    res.status(err.status || 500).json({
        status_code: err.status_code || EStatusCode.FAIL,
        message: err.message,
        error: err.error
    });
});

let server = app.listen(config.server.port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is now running at port ${config.server.port}`);
});
```

Also I'm using the mysql server. When the server starts, I created a mysql Pool, and whenever there's a request, it gets a connection from the mysql pool. After each request ends, I did release the pool connection. I found that sometimes it throws an error about "Connection already released". I don't know if I handles the mysql connection correctly and causing this problem. Please help, thanks!

Comment: This is not related to Express. It's **Nginx**, could be for several reasons. e.g: the process is not up.

Comment: @mas To explain more, the server is run by "PM2". If I starts the server with 4 clusters, this problem is rarely happened.

Comment: @mas During the error, what is the tail output of ```pm2 logs``` ?

Comment: @mas There is no error shown in pm2 logs

Comment: 1- You'll need to add logs to determine if the source of the issue is the application itself. Use a logger library such as [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) to save the logs and check them when the error occurs. 2- Check out this [gude](https://bobcares.com/blog/502-bad-gateway-nginx/) might be helpful if you're certain that the issue source isn't the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Error is not related to express.js, Nginx throws this error when your process is down, actually what happening is that in some scenario you are trying to  release the pool connection even when pool connection is released. so this causes the process to crash and nginx sends 502 error as service is down for a short time.

See in you code connection ends on 404 but error is passed to 
 error handling middleware where if error occur it tries to rollback the db changes.
 So db connection is closed before rollbacking changes.
 You have to handle this part. remove  await req.db.end(); from 404 handler and place it after await req.db.rollback();

```js
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
   // await req.db.end(); // connection ends here on 404 but error is passed to 
 //error handling middleware where if error occur it tries to rollback the db //changes.
// So db connection is closed before rollbacking changes.
// You have to handle this part. remove this  await req.db.end(); from here and //place it after await req.db.rollback();  
    // Route not found.
    const error = new Error();
    error.message = 'API not found.';
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
})

// On Error Handling
app.use(async (err, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    await req.db.rollback();
    await req.db.end()  // place it here
    console.log(err);
    res.status(err.status || 500).json({
        status_code: err.status_code || EStatusCode.FAIL,
        message: err.message,
        error: err.error
    });
});
```